# Query performance | stuck if more than 2 joins are in sql query

Tags: query, automationstudio, data-views

I'm trying to get Total number of clicks per each URL for Newsletters and joining 3 data views: click, job and sent.

The query was successfully executed when I tested with 2 joins on click and job data views. But once I added join on sent, it stuck in automation flow.

```sql
SELECT s.EventDate,
    CASE
        WHEN j.EmailName LIKE 'A%' THEN 'A'
        WHEN j.EmailName LIKE 'B%' THEN 'B'
    END AS EmailName, c.URL, count(c.URL) as Totals
FROM _Click c
JOIN _Job j ON c.JobID=j.JobID
JOIN _Sent s ON j.JobID=s.JobID
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,s.EventDate,GetDate()) < 7
AND (j.EmailName LIKE 'A%'
OR j.EmailName LIKE 'B%')
GROUP BY s.EventDate,
    CASE
        WHEN j.EmailName LIKE 'A%' THEN 'A'
        WHEN j.EmailName LIKE 'B%' THEN 'B'
    END, c.URL
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are likely facing a timeout issue as the DataViews are not the most performant sources and joining 3 of them with any volume is likely a huge resource draw.

You are likely going to have to split this into at least 2 queries to get around the 30 minute timeout that exists on SFMC.

I would recommend something like this for the first one:

```sql
SELECT s.EventDate,
    substring(j.EmailName,0,1) AS EmailName,
    j.jobid
FROM _Job j
JOIN _Sent s ON j.JobID=s.JobID
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,s.EventDate,GetDate()) < 7
AND (j.EmailName LIKE 'A%'
OR j.EmailName LIKE 'B%')
```

This one would go to a staging DE (`myStageDE`) and I would have this overwrite on each run. You don't need to have a group by in this case - you would need the jobid as the pkey to match against the clicks in the second query.

Next follow it up with the Click DV Query:

```sql
SELECT s.EventDate,
       s.EmailName, 
       c.URL, 
       count(c.URL) as Totals
FROM _Click c
INNER JOIN [myStageDE] s ON c.JobID = s.JobID
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, c.EventDate,GetDate()) < 7
GROUP BY s.EventDate, s.EmailName, c.URL
```

This will then be output to your final DE and greatly reduce the risk of time outs.

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington! Actually, I followed this documentation with 3 joins together /https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_find_subscribers_with_no_opens_or_clicks_ref.htm&type=5/ and it works:

Comment: @k_r_y - glad that you found an answer, but just be careful as volume increases, the risk of time outs on the query will increase as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CONVERT(DATE, s.EventDate) as EventDate,
    CASE
        WHEN j.EmailName LIKE 'A%' THEN 'A'
        WHEN j.EmailName LIKE 'B%' THEN 'Bt'
    END AS EmailName, c.URL, COUNT(c.URL) as TotalClicks
FROM [_sent] s
LEFT JOIN [_job] j
ON s.JobID = j.JobID
LEFT JOIN [_click] c
ON s.JobID = c.JobID and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,s.EventDate,GetDate()) < 7
AND (j.EmailName LIKE 'A%'
OR j.EmailName LIKE 'B%')
AND s.JobID = j.JobID
AND c.URL IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, s.EventDate),
    CASE
        WHEN j.EmailName LIKE 'A%' THEN 'A'
        WHEN j.EmailName LIKE 'B%' THEN 'B'
    END, c.URL
```